# how to display data from online database in android

Tags: java, android

I'm quite new to android apps development.I am currently facing some problem with displaying data from online database in application.
What I know is we should create a `SQLite` so that user can get the data from the `SQLite`.
But is it necessary to create all of my data in to `SQLite` in order to display the data inside the table to user ?
Is there any other way to display my online database data into the apps directly ?

Comment: do you know about webservices and apis?

Comment: I have no idea about it,but thankyou to provide me such keyword.I will try to google it

Comment: It depends on your requirements, if you want to make offline app which uses internet rarely then u need to create SQLite,or else internet is not the problem then get the data from server using webservices may be json or xml then parse that data by creating model and utilize that model for rendering data, go through this tutorial - https://www.javatpoint.com/android-web-service

Comment: check this link out https://medium.com/@peterekeneeze/parsing-remote-json-to-recyclerview-android-1ad927e96d58

Comment: For online databases, you can make use of a `mySQL` database (hosted on a website), `SQLite` is for local databases on your phone. What you probably want is to synchronize your online database with your local database. However, there are also other possibilities to store your data online, such as Firebase. It really depends on what you want to do.

Comment: Previously I have created a sales control system(web base) , now my boss request me to learn about android apps and using the same database with the system, and my database is host by hosting company at C penal phpMyAdmin.

Comment: I can see you're new to android...please refer official android docs : https://developer.android.com/docs/  and a basic tutorial from : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/  to get the basic idea of how write webservices and APIs in your android in order to fetch data from web database

Comment: there's lib called volley to help you in your work, refer here : https://medium.com/android-grid/how-to-fetch-json-data-using-volley-and-put-it-to-recyclerview-android-studio-383059a12d1e

Comment: @QiuXue You can create web apis in php. Please refer this https://www.codeofaninja.com/2017/02/create-simple-rest-api-in-php.html.  Once you create the apis you can use Retroft library to call the apis. It will also help you to parse the response in POJO classes.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer set field in millisecondi unix type on sqllite for not create localization date problems wend you work on different database o installations options in differents machine/device.